# How do I handle non-recurring Paypal subscriptions? Subscription expires immediately

Tags: paypal, sandbox, subscription

I'm working on a site that does non-recurring subscriptions, currently testing it on Paypal Sandbox. Let's say duration is 1 week (t3 = W, p3 = 1). I didn't include src and srt variables in the form. From what little information I have read related to this, a non-recurring subscription counts as a one-off and immediately expires the subscription. I want it to still lapse the duration and subscr_eot be called one week later. The application is run on Java/JSP.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it needs to be handled on your side, not on PayPal's.

You receive a payment for your services, and attach an expiration date to that user in *your* database.  He's only allowed to log into your site before his account expires.

Comment: its seems non-intuitive... and forces an added layer of complexity to our ipn-listener, wheras paypal could just send that eot at the eot... :(

Answer (score 0):

So, I now devided the fee into two parts: eg, the one year fee is $10, than I charge $9.95 as the one year trial amount a1, and $0.05 as a non-recurring daily fee (a3) for only one day.
Seems that does it... at least the EOT is not immediately send...

Just have to explain your customers that this awkward payment plan is because of a Paypal peculiarity...